OpenTelemetry for React native?
I have worked with OpenTelemetry on React projects, but now I want to see if we can add traces and gather telemetry data with React Native apps?
I tried looking up on the internet, it doesn't show anything except for this thread which looks inactive: https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-js/issues/1089
Can anyone help me or guide me if there's a way on doing this? if not open telemetry, are there other open source tools/libraries doing this?  I can see that New Relic and other enterprise tools are offering this solution in React Native, but I am looking for something open source.

Currently, OpenTelemetry does not support React Native.
I've seen some other tools that might help like:

https://github.com/microsoft/applicationinsights-react-native
https://github.com/DataDog/dd-sdk-reactnative
https://github.com/signalfx/splunk-otel-react-native
https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/react-native/performance/

However, you can also try to rather investigate instrumenting the underlying runtime, which might be hard for a mobile app author to do
